# C# vsto drag drop to cell, get the cell object before dropping

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

The following code works well. I can drag an item from listview and drop it into a cell.

```
private void treeView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
        {
             treeView1.DoDragDrop(DragData.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy); 
        }
    }
}
```

My question is whether it is possible that I can change the DragDropEffects, according the cell I will drop.

For example, it is not allowed to drop the item to cell[A1], so I hope the DragDropEffects can be 'none' , including the mouse style should be a disallowed mark when the mouse is only on the cell[A1].

Hope I can find a place to write following codes.

```
private void mouse_on(Excel.Range targetRange){
    if(targetRange.Address == "A1"){
        DragDropEffects.None;
    }else{
        DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTO (nor Excel) doesn't provide anything for that.

You may try to use the [Locked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836172(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Range class which indicates if the object is locked. This property returns True if the object is locked, False if the object can be modified when the sheet is protected, or Null if the specified range contains both locked and unlocked cells.

The [Protect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611(v=office.15).aspx) method protects a worksheet so that it cannot be modified.

So, you can protect the worksheet and set the Locked property to false for the area where you can drop the data. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried, but I cannot set a cell to unlock when the sheet is protected. Meanwhile it have no effects that I set a cell to lock.